# auth.sessionChange Facebook event stopped working after enabling OAuth 2 in Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm reliant on using:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
// my update user token code goes here
});
```

It was all fine and dandy until I upgraded the javascript SDK to the oauth2 version.
Anyone know why? Other events seem to work fine though, like the edge.create.

It's just the `auth.sessionChange` event is no longer being fired for me.

Has the name been replaced to use `auth.statusChange`? Because that also doesn't work for me. I also see there is auth.authResponseChange.

Quite frankly, I don't know which is the real one, seems like docs haven't been updated (?). Nevertheless, none of them are working for me now.

Answer (score 5):

According to the upgrade guide auth.sessionChange was replaced with auth.authResponseChange

> You may still subscribe to a collection of events as before:
>   auth.login, auth.logout, and auth.statusChange still work, but
>   auth.sessionChange is deprecated and being replaced with
>   auth.authResponseChange. Of course, auth.sessionChange will continue
>   to work until at least the October 1 transition time, and
>   auth.authResponseChange is only relevant when OAuth2 has been enabled.
>   When OAuth 2.0 is enabled, authorization responses—not sessions—are
>   passed to all callbacks for connected users.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/